# Parse PFUserSession Token Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, parse-platform, pfuser

I am making an app in which I need to use

```
[PFUser enableRevocableSessionInBackground]
```

However, when I add this to my app delegate, it says there is no know class method.  Am I forgetting to import a header?

Answer (score 0):

That's a great guess.

Try doing:

```
#include "Parse/PFUser.h"
```

or

```
#include "PFUser.h"
```

Comment: try `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` also.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that. No luck

Comment: Are you including Parse anywhere else in your app?  If you control click on `enableRevocableSessionInBackground` in your code, will the "jump to definition" menu choice in Xcode take you to the correct definition in PFUser.h ?